# A tame(ish) fragment of second-order logic

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals, second-order-logic

This question is about a tame(?) fragment of second-order logic with the standard semantics $\mathsf{SOL}$, motivated by the Tarski-Vaught test. The general setup is as follows. Given structures $\mathfrak{A},\mathfrak{B}$ and a logic $\mathcal{L}$, write $\mathfrak{A}\trianglelefteq_{\mathcal{L}}\mathfrak{B}$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ is a substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$ and for every $\mathcal{L}$-formula $\varphi$ with parameters from $\mathfrak{A}$ we have $$\varphi^\mathfrak{B}\not=\emptyset\implies \varphi^\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{A}\not=\emptyset.$$

Tarski-Vaught says that $\trianglelefteq_\mathsf{FOL}$ coincides with $\preccurlyeq_{\mathsf{FOL}}$, but in general this breaks down: note that whenever $\trianglelefteq_\mathcal{L}$ and $\preccurlyeq_\mathcal{L}$ coincide we get a downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem for $\mathcal{L}$ by counting formulas. However, we can ask how *much* elementarity $\trianglelefteq_\mathcal{L}$ guarantees. Specifically, say that the *TV-fragment* of $\mathcal{L}$ is the set $\mathcal{L}_{TV}$ of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\varphi$ for which we have $$\mathfrak{A}\trianglelefteq_\mathcal{L}\mathfrak{B}\implies\varphi^\mathfrak{A}=\varphi^\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{A}.$$

I'm interested in the expressive power of $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ as a logic in its own right. Despite having the downward Lowenheim-Skolem property, it is much stronger than first-order logic. For example, well-foundedness is $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$-characterizable$^1$; this means that there is an $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$-sentence pinning down $\mathbb{N}$ up to isomorphism, which in turn implies that the $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$-definable relations on $\mathbb{N}$ are exactly the $\mathsf{SOL}$-definable ones. Beyond this, not much is clear to me. The following seems like a good next point to tackle:

> Working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is an extendible cardinal," can the strong compactness number$^2$ of $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ be strictly less than the smallest extendible cardinal?

At present I don't see anything preventing the strong compactness number of $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ from being *extremely* small - although of course since $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ has the downward Lowenheim-Skolem property it must be uncountable by Lindstrom's Theorem.

---

$^1$Since well-foundedness is preserved downwards, it's enough to show (working in a language with a distinguished binary relation symbol $<$) that if $\mathfrak{A}\trianglelefteq_{\mathsf{SOL}}\mathfrak{B}$ and $<^\mathfrak{B}$ is illfounded then $<^\mathfrak{A}=<^\mathfrak{B}\cap\mathfrak{A}$ is illfounded. Consider first the formula $\psi(x)\equiv$ "The initial segment of $<$ below $x$ is ill-founded." We have $\psi^\mathfrak{B}\not=\emptyset$, so there must be some $a\in\mathfrak{A}$ which is in the ill-founded part of $<^\mathfrak{B}$. But now for each $u\in\mathfrak{A}$ in the ill-founded part of $<^\mathfrak{B}$, consider the formula $\theta_u(y)\equiv$ "$y<u$ and $y$ is in the ill-founded part of $<$." Applying $\triangleleft_{\mathsf{SOL}}$-ness, we get that the set of elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ which are in the ill-founded part of $\mathfrak{B}$ has no $<^\mathfrak{B}$-minimal element, which (together with its above-established nonemptiness) implies that $<^\mathfrak{A}$ is ill-founded as desired.

$^2$The *strong compactness number* of a logic $\mathcal{L}$, if it exists at all, is the least cardinal $\kappa$ such that every unsatisfiable $\mathcal{L}$-theory has an unsatisfiable subtheory of cardinality $<\kappa$. Large cardinals imply the existence of strong compactness numbers; in particular, second-order logic has a strong compactness number iff there is an extendible cardinal, in which case its strong compactness number is the least extendible. As an amusing aside, [Vopenka's Principle](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29310/8133) turns out to be equivalent to the existence of strong compactness numbers for all logics [in a precise sense](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273786).

Comment: Note that $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ as a **set** is horribly nasty: the set of second-order sentences which are $\trianglelefteq_{\mathsf{SOL}}$-invariant is about as complicated as the set of second-order tautologies. Only by restricting attention to $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$'s nature as an abstract logic alone can we hope for tameness.

Comment: Is it obvious that $\mathsf{SOL}_{TV}$ is closed under conjunctions? (Also are you extending the definition to formulas on multiple variables too?)

Comment: Oh, I guess that is actually pretty clear.

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, on both counts - although because we're allowing parameters in formulas, the one-variable condition implies the more-variables condition.

Comment: @JamesHanson The number-of-variables issue gets more complicated when we look at logics which allow infinitely many variables, e.g. versions of this construction for $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\lambda}$, but as long as we're only playing with finitely many variables at once we're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move this off the unanswered queue, note that user Farmer S. [gave an affirmative answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/388686/8133) at MathOverflow. They actually showed a general result: roughly speaking, that any time we have downward Lowenheim-Skolem we automatically get a compactness number at most the smallest supercompact cardinal. In particular, since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that if there is an extendible cardinal then $(i)$ there is a supercompact cardinal and $(ii)$ the least supercompact is smaller than the least extendible this does fully answer the question above.